# How can I check if a a value matches a value in an array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT users.uuid
FROM users
JOIN users_ext ON users.uuid = users_ext.uuid
WHERE TRUE AND
 ($1 IS NULL OR users.country IN (ARRAY[$1])) AND
 ($2 IS NULL OR users.bonus_points IN (ARRAY[$2])) AND
```

Although I am getting the error: "operator does not exist: text = text[]"

I have tried

```
$1 IS NULL OR users.country IN ANY(ARRAY[$1]))
```

But still does not work. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Use =ANY() to make it a valid piece of SQL. Check the manual https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html

Comment: So is this postgres or mysql???  They are 2 completely different products.

Answer (score 0):

This error might be caused by data type mismatch between column and parameter used in comparison. You can check if data type of $1 matches the data type of the users.country column.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that you need to change it to:

```
($1 IS NULL OR users.country IN ($1))
```

I am not sure about what $1 / $2 is - could you provide example?